# gpg: selecting card failed: No such device

Tags: gnupg, ubuntu-20.04

I have ubuntu 20.04 machine and installed gpg and related tools using below commad

`sudo apt install gpg gnupg gnupg-pkcs11-scd`

But when i run `gpg --card-status`, I get below error

```
gpg: selecting card failed: No such device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: No such device
```

Should I install anything else for this ?

Answer (score 7):

Try forcing a restart of the gpg-agent with `pkill gpg-agent`

```
➜ gpg --card-status
gpg: selecting card failed: Service is not running
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Service is not running

➜ pkill gpg-agent

➜ gpg --card-status
Reader ...........: Yubico YubiKey OTP FIDO CCID
...
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems like pcscd.service is inactive by default, have you tried (re)starting it?

```
sudo service pcscd restart
```

Comment: in my case restarting gpg-agent didn't help and pcscd service was running. Only after restarting pcscd service I was able to read the key. I'm on Fedora 38, GPG v2.4.0,  pcsc-lite v1.9.9

Comment: Fedora 39, GPG v2.4.4, pcsc-lite v2.0.1 also requires pcscd restart after each hotplug of YubiKey.